# Bookmarks access iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, safari, bookmarks

Hey guys, how do you access bookmarks with the sdk? I'm currently making a browser of sorts for iPad. I made the address bar and added the bookmarks button but I don't see any documentation on accessing bookmarks.
Basically, I would like to know how to access Safari Bookmarks. Anyone know how to do this?

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This currently isn't possible using the iPhone sdk (non-jailbroken).

On a jailbroken phone, these can be found here:

```
/var/mobile/Library/Safari/Bookmarks.plist
```

Comment: This question/answer is from the time of iOS 3, is it not? Any chance that this has changed now that we're on iOS 6?